# Receiving blank style value when hovering (Java Selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the style opacity for an element while I hover over it and compare it to the other elements on the page. When I hover over an element the value I receive is blank/null but when I inspect it with firebug it is style="opacity: 1;". The code will always fail when I try to assert.asserttrue a value to the hovered element. Please help!

```
public void RegTestID7(){
        skaneSelma();
        navigeraBlodtryck();
        fordrojningKort();
        overlayKiller();
        fordrojningKort();
        String opacity1 = "opacity: 1;";
        String opacity02 = "opacity: 0.2;";
        hoverOverLink("indicator__SE");
        fordrojningKort();
        String landetOpacity = runner.getDriverWrapper().findElement(By.id("indicator__SE")).getAttribute("style");
        Assert.assertTrue(landetOpacity.equals(opacity1));
        System.out.println(landetOpacity);
        String selmaOpacity = runner.getDriverWrapper().findElement(By.id("indicator__SE2321000131-E000000007615")).getAttribute("style");
        Assert.assertTrue(selmaOpacity.equals(opacity02));
        System.out.println(selmaOpacity);
        String skaneOpacity = runner.getDriverWrapper().findElement(By.id("indicator__12")).getAttribute("style");
        System.out.println(skaneOpacity);
        System.out.println("dfdf");
        Assert.assertTrue(skaneOpacity.equals(opacity1));   
        fordrojningLang();
        }
```

Comment: Before assert, print your variable, what will you see?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas I solved it by using .isEmpty, however it is not the correct way to tackle the issue. Assert.assertTrue(runner.getDriverWrapper().findElement(By.id("indicator__SE")).getAttribute("style").isEmpty());